# Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Cat[M]>'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand typescript's conditional generics so I have written a function to call a method of `Cat` using the method name string.

```
// union of all methods names in T
type Methods<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type Cat = {
    meow(n: string): string;
    eat(n: number): number;
};

function foo<M extends Methods<Cat>>(c: Cat, method: M, ...params: Parameters<Cat[M]>): ReturnType<Cat[M]> {
    return c[method](...params);
}
```

Here it is known that `M` is a method name in `Cat`, and typescript is able to determine its parameters and return type in the type signature. But in the expression `c[method](...params)` it seems to forget what method we're calling, so returns `string | number`. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Read the other answer for the explanation... if it helps, translating the code from the other answer here yields [this](https://tsplay.dev/OwEAgw).

Comment: I've added this to the growing list of questions that run into lack of support for correlated unions, see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)